# Successive approximations of a function (taylor formula derivation)

Tags: taylor-expansion

I am reading about the ways of function approximation which led to Taylor's formula.
I understand that in a very close neighbourhood of the point **a** we can approximate **f(x)** by **f(a)**. However this is very rough approximation and just by looking at the function graph we see that a tangent line can do a much better job of approximation. So we can find the tangent line formula by calculating the derivative of f(x) and rearranging terms a bit:

$$\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} = f'(a) $$
thus
$$ y = f(a) + f'(a)(x-a)$$

so far so good but just by looking at the graph of the tangent it's obvious that this approximation will get worst and worst the further away **x** is from **a**.

So now what can we do next to approximate **f(x)** even better? Author of the book I read suddenly, without any derivation shows this expression:

$$\frac{f(x) - [f(a) + f'(a)(x-a)]}{(x-a)^2}$$

It closely resembles second derivative but it isn't that. I am especially confused about the denominator $$(x-a)^2$$ what is its origin? How can we prove / explain it geometrically, base on the function graph I linked below?

My explanation of the next step on a way to better approximation after the tangent line is we want the tangent to **travel** the graph according to our delegation from **a** described by factor $$(x-a)$$ Is it correct thinking?

[Function and its "tangential" approximation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMNJq.png)

Comment: The next approximation is by a second degree polynomial (i.e. a circle, ellipse, parabola or hyperbola) instead of a first degree polynomial (i.e. a straight line). You make the quadratic a) pass through $f(a)$, b) have the same slope at $a$ as the function does (i.e. the first derivatives agree) and c) have the same concavity at $a$ as the function does (i.e. the second derivatives agree). That's three conditions on the three coefficients of the quadratic. It's not clear to me what you mean by "delegation from a".

Answer (score 1):

We have that 
$$
f(x) = f(a) + f'(a)\left( {x - a} \right) + {1 \over 2}f''(a)\left( {x - a} \right)^{\,2}  + O\left( {\left( {x - a} \right)^{\,3} } \right)
$$
so that we can write
$$
{1 \over 2}f''(a) \approx {{f(x) - f(a) - f'(a)\left( {x - a} \right)} \over {\left( {x - a} \right)^{\,2} }}
$$
i.e., (probably ) they are telling you that, once you have $f(a), f'(a)$ you can *estimate* $1/2f''(a)$ in that way instead of directly differentiate twice.

Comment: The question is how was that $$\frac{1}{2}f''(a)(x-a)^2$$ derived in the first place?

Comment: that is just the (2nd term of the ) Taylor series